# Convert multiple time formats to datetime in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe with a "time" column that counts every millisecond, which I would like to add to a "start_time" in order to create a time_expanded column.

How do you convert a column of different time formats to DateTime?

Example of "time" and "start_time" columns:

[image]

I.e. I want to convert this `pd.Series` to datetime, where first item is 0.1 sec, second item is 5.1 sec., third item is 42 min. 5.1 sec. and the fourth item is 1 hour 42 min. 5.1 sec.
`df["time"] = ["0.1", "5.1", "42:05.1", "1:42:05.1"]`

Comment: Could you please provide a [mre] as text instead of image? Copy and paste is better than OCR ;-)

Comment: Btw. your 'time' column is a duration, so you're looking for `pd.to_timedelta`

Answer (score 0):

To convert column in datetime, use:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['time_expanded'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time_expanded'])
```

Then

```
df['time_expanded'].values = df['time_expanded'].values + df['time'].values
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it unfortunately doesn't work.
I can't convert `df["time"]` to datetime as it contains different time formats (see attached picture), times like 0.1 ms., 3.08 sec., 56:09.8 min., 1:34:43.6 hours.